# How to use jquery autocomplete in my web page in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I have source code for search engine auto-complete from online.

These are the files,

Here is style.css:

```
.autocomplete-w1 { background:url(img/shadow.png) no-repeat bottom right; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; margin:8px 0 0 6px; /* IE6 fix: */ _background:none; _margin:0; }
.autocomplete { border:1px solid #999; background:#FFF; cursor:default; text-align:left; max-height:350px; overflow:auto; margin:-6px 6px 6px -6px; /* IE6 specific: */ _height:350px;  _margin:0; _overflow-x:hidden; }
.autocomplete .selected { background:#F0F0F0; }
.autocomplete div { padding:2px 5px; white-space:nowrap; }
.autocomplete strong { font-weight:normal; color:#3399FF; }
```

Here is my link http://jsfiddle.net/xwm390o5/2/

But my page is not working,

I can't able to understand how to use these auto-complete js files in my web page.

Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: No JS files included, wrong selector used to init autocomplete.

Comment: and input tag not closed

Comment: @ShaunakD  I have a js files, i didn't have js link.. may i know, how to add link ? thanks

Comment: The JSFiddle is missing any external JQuery and JQuery UI script files

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwm390o5/1/). Add ID to your input tag. Close it. And include `<script>` files in your actual project.

Comment: I am struggling with create jsfiddle., thanks

Comment: @ShaunakD: may i know, how to external resources, because i don't have a link, i have only files. thanks

Comment: Well, maybe before doing something you should learn "base things" about how all these work? If you don't know how to include scripts and how they work, it's time to learn this. There are tons of books, online guides, seminars and so on.

Comment: Google Search [Here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+include+script+files+in+html&oq=how+to+include+script+files+in+html&aqs=chrome..69i57.8029j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the autocomplete directly to the input element.

```
<input id="autocompleteInput" type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'/>

$( "#autocompleteInput" ).autocomplete({
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwm390o5/4/)

Comment: Thanks, but i got a source code from this link https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/, when i type any letter, that particular letter will be colored right?.. but in yours no colored,, can you please help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Non JS Solution: If you are using HTML5 then you can use HTML list attribute in textbox and tag datalist for option.

```
<p><label>Tutorial:</label><input type='text' list="availableTutorials" id="automplete" name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
  <datalist id="availableTutorials">
      <option value="ActionScript">
      <option value="Boostrap">
      <option value="Google Chrome">
      <option value="c">
      <option value="c++">
</datalist>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/438tu6dc/)